# Why does VBA give an Object Error when I paste into another workbook and SaveAs

Tags: vba, save-as

For some ungodly reason, when I want to SaveAs I get a "Method 'SaveAs' of obejct' _Workbook". I know this has been approached from multiple angles on stack overflow, but I just couldn't understand.

My code is very simple. Just copy the (manually) selected code on the macro workbook and open a data-less template from my drive. Then I paste into Range "A2". I would like to save as , but under a different name, one with today's date.

Please kindly advise, I've lost nearly all hope.

The error stems from the saveas method.

```
Sub AutoEmail()

    Call trimFunction

    Dim sSaveFileName As String
    sSaveFileName = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")

    Selection.Copy

    With Selection.Interior
             .Pattern = xlSolid
             .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
             .Color = 10092543
             .TintAndShade = 0
             .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="U:\FuturesClearing\Wires\Futures Wires Email _ 
        Templates\Brokerage to Futures TDA.xlsx"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\FuturesClearing\Wires\Futures Wires _ 
    Email Templates\Brokerage to Futures TDA " & sSaveFileName & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't have a forward slash in the filename - `sSaveFileName = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY"` won't work.

Comment: Consider using `Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd")` instead, first because it's using characters legal in a filename, but also because it makes the file names sortable, *and* non-ambiguous to rest-of-the-world people that might come across the file. Also, "yyyy-MM-dd" is ISO standard and internationally understood, whereas "MM/DD/YYYY" only makes sense in the US (if at all).

Comment: Thank you! It works now, using legal characters